# Is it possible in Javascript to wrap public class instance fields in getter/setter before instantiation of that class?

Tags: javascript

In the snippet below I'm replacing a `msg` field of `Foo` with the getter/setter of that field, the descriptor of which now is stored outside the class.

```js
class Foo {
  msg = 'Hello, World!';
}

let foo = new Foo();
let msgDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(foo, 'msg');

Object.defineProperty(foo, 'msg', {
  get() {
    console.log(`Getting msg: «${msgDescriptor.value}»`);
    return msgDescriptor.value;
  },

  set(value) {
    console.log(`Setting msg to: «${value}»`);
    msgDescriptor.value = value;
  }
})

foo.msg = 'Bye, World!';

console.log(foo.msg);
```

---

Is it possible to do the replacement before `Foo` instantiation, so that I can modify `Foo` once and not do that on every instance?

**EDIT**: assuming `Foo` is external class, new example below:

```js
// Foo.js
export class Foo {
  msg = 'Hello, World!';
}
```

```js
// index.js
import { Foo } from './Foo.js'
let foo = new Foo();
let msgDescriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(foo, 'msg');

Object.defineProperty(foo, 'msg', {
    get() {
        console.log(`Getting msg: «${msgDescriptor.value}»`);
        return msgDescriptor.value;
    },

    set(value) {
        console.log(`Setting msg to: «${value}»`);
        msgDescriptor.value = value;
    }
})

foo.msg = 'Bye, World!';

console.log(foo.msg);
```

Comment: `class Foo { get msg() { ... } set msg(v) { ... } }`…?

Comment: @deceze the point is to define getter/setter of already defined property outside a class.

Comment: `Object.defineProperty(Foo, 'msg', {` why not define the property on the class directly?

Comment: Have the constructor create a property descriptor, and have the class-defined getter/setter use it…? Expose the descriptor as property?

Comment: @deceze imagine that `Foo` is some external class that I'm importing in my project, I don't have the access to it's definition, so I can't modify it directly.

Comment: `Object.defineProperty(this, 'msg',...)` inside the constructor?

Comment: If you can't modify Foo, then it's hard to do this only once. At the very least you'd need to monkey-patch it. Wrapping a factory around it sounds like the most useful idea without modifying the class itself.

Comment: @deceze assuming `Foo` is external class, using a factory means still modifying it after instantiation?

Comment: By necessity yes. If the class won't do it itself, then you *can* only modify it after instantiation.

Comment: Are you using typescript?

Comment: @blaumeise20 yeah.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried many different ways of doing it, but no way seems to work correctly. It always gives you a TypeScript error. I understand what you want to do but it is not possible that way. What you could do is to create an extension function which you pass the instance to and this function extends the instance.